# How do I get a versioned asset URL in a Sass stylesheet?

Tags: css, playframework, sass

In a view, I'm able to use the following code to get the versioned asset URL. How can I achieve this inside of a Sass stylesheet file? I'm effectively looking for the equivalent of Rails' [image-url](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass) but can't seem to find the same function for the Play Framework (version 2.5).

```
@routes.Assets.versioned("images/favicon.png")
```